How to highlight a vertex in Edit Mode?
I'm working on an addon, and I have an operation that manipulate vertices in some way.
The problem is that after this manipulation I want the user to easily see which vertices were effected by the operation. I'm currently trying to draw over them with color using the GPU module, but I couldn't find a way to show the drawing only in edit mod, and update the drawing when I move a vertex.
Is there any way to do such highlight?
